# Implementing star rating in Ruby on Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, semantic-ui

So I have a ruby on rails form that is using semantic ui rating (stars).

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html

Does anyone know how to pass these star values back and forth using ruby? For example, if a user rates something 3 stars, how do I pass that to the backend.

I have a long list of 15 attributes that a user can rate (food, atmosphere, pricing etc) for a given restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be through APIs, you can create GET APIs to fetch the ratings and POST APIs to modify them!

I'm assuming that you're using the whole package, if you're planning to use only the CSS of semantic UI then you can use it in your erb files as well.

Cheers!